# Injecting property values from property file or xml file into PreAuthorize(...) java annotation (Unresolved)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-annotations, spring-el

I've asked this question in my previous post here: [SpEL for spring security: Passing Values from XML to Java based SpEL configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625465/spel-for-spring-security-passing-values-from-xml-to-java-based-spel-configurati/19765567#19765567). But it wasn't yet resolved. I want to inject values either from an xml configuration or from external file into `@PreAuthorize(...)` annotation. It is not easy like injecting by using `@Value` annotation.

To recall the question, I provide the following information.

1. I have the following xml configuration file (example.xml) that
       has properties and initialized its corresponding values.

   ```xml
   <beans>
       <bean id="userBean" class="x.y.User">
       <property name="name" value="A"/>
       <property name="userId" value="33"/>

       <bean id="customerBean" class="x.y.Customer">
           <property name="name" value="B"/>
           <property name="customerId" value="33"/>
       </bean>
   </beans>
   ```
2. I have the following external properties file
   (example.properties) inside /WEB-INF folder. This file is an
   alternative for the XML configuration file mentioned above.

   ```
   user.id = 33
   customer.id =33
   ```
3. I have property policy holder configuration in my applicationContext.xml file

   ```xml
   <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/*.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

   <bean id="propertyConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
         p:location="/WEB-INF/example.properties" p:ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders="true" />
   ```
4. I have two model classes: `User` and `Customer`

   ```java
   public class User {
       private int userId;

   public int getUserId() {
           return userId;
       }
   }

   public class Customer {
       private int customerId;

       public int getCustomerId(){
           return customerId;
       }
   }
   ```
5. I have another service/controller class which I want to restrict
   the `'edit'` method by using `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

   `The restriction`: The method is allowed (authorized to be executed)
   if and only if `'userId'` and `'customerId'` are evaluated equal!.

   To achieve the restriction, I want to consider two ways

   1. by injecting `'userId'` and `'customerId'` values from the xml file(example.xml) into expression 1 below. The expressions I used in
      this are suggested by Rob Winch (Thank you Rob!). However, Spring
      couldn't evaluate the expression.
   2. by injecting `'userId'` and `'customerId'` values from the external properties file(example.properties) into expression 2
      below. Similarly, spring couldn't evaluate this expression as well.

      ```java
      @Service("..") or @Controller
      public class MyMainClass {

          //Expression 1
          @PreAuthorize("@userBean.userId == @customerBean.customerId")
              public Boolean edit(User user, Customer custmer)  {
          return true;
          }

          //Expression 2
          ////I've tried other ways as well, but end up with similar exceptions
          @PreAuthorize("${user.id} == ${customer.id}")
          public Boolean edit(User user, Customer customer)  {
              return true;
          }
      }
      ```

My questions:

Q1. What are the right expressions that I must put inside the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to inject values from the xml file (example.xml) or from property file (example.properties) into the `@PreAuthorize(...)` expression, then it can be easily evaluated?

Q2. Point me if I did mistakes other than the expressions.

Q3. Its like a $1,000,000.00 question for me as I am fed up as hell to solve this issue!!!. So please help me out as much as you can!.

Comment: Your second expression only works in `@Value` annotations as those refer to placeholders and not an expression. Can you post/add the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using properties file and you want to access them in controller classes you have to add `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my.properties"/>` in your servlet context xml file, after that you can use @Value annotation to get the values of that properties. e.g.
`my.properties` file contains `some.userid=33` so you would access this property using:

```
@Value("${some.userid}")
private int someId;
```

but to be sure for testing purpose i would set ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to false and in case it can't resolve properties file i would know where the error is coming from...

hope it helps.